# Calling getchar from assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, cygwin, x86-64, getchar

I am attempting to write a simple test program in assembly that simply calls `getchar` and passes the returned value to `putchar`. My current code looks like this:

```
.global main
.text

main:
mov $12,%rbx
.head:
call getchar
mov %rax,%rcx
call putchar
dec %rbx
test %rbx,%rbx
jne .head
call exit
```

The program is compiled using `gcc -o prog prog.s` on Windows 10 with Cygwin (with the code above being saved to `prog.s`).

What I expect this to do is read from stdin 12 times (arbitrarily), and immediately send 12 read characters to stdout. In other words, when running the program from the console, I would expect it to wait until something is entered into the console and enter is pressed. Instead, what actually happens is, when I run it, it immediately prints 12 seemingly nonsensical characters and exits:

```
������������
```

In previous programs that called a C function which used `getchar` within them, then printed the read character as well as the result for `ferror(stdin)`. `getchar` apparently returned -1, and the error flag of stdin was set as soon as `getchar` was called. Why might this be happening? Especially given that a program written purely in C can call `getchar` with no problems.

Comment: Is it possible that you actually used the Windows Subsystem for Linux or something, where the calling convention passes the first arg in RDI, not RCX?  Maybe try adding `mov %eax, %edi` as well?  That wouldn't explain `getchar` returning immediately, though.  I'm surprised that `call putchar` linked on Windows, where C symbol names normally get a leading underscore, like `call _putchar`.  Use `file prog` to see if it's an ELF64 executable (Linux), or Windows PE/COFF.  Especially since you name it `prog`, not `prog.exe`.

Comment: I used `-o prog` when compiling, but it still saved to `prog.exe`, and `file prog` reveals it is a PE32+ executable, x86-64, for MS-Windows.

Comment: Add `-mconsole` to the gcc command line just to be sure.

Comment: Adding `-mconsole` made no difference to the behavior or result of `file prog`.

Comment: Note you are misaligning the stack and not setting up shadow space as required by the calling convention. Inserting `subq $40, %rsp` after `main:` makes it work using `wine` on linux at least.

Comment: Why is it that 40 - 5 qwords - is the value needed to be added to the stack? Is there a sort of guaranteed alignment or misalignment of the stack when the program begins?

Comment: You need to add 8 for alignment (since `CALL` pushes another 8 bytes). The 32 are for the shadow space. Consult calling convention documentation. Did that make it work?

Comment: @Jester: I noticed the lack of allocating new shadow space, but this `main` doesn't return: it calls `exit`.  Other than alignment, it should be fine to let `getchar` step on main's return address and above if we're not going to return.  Stack misalignment is normally crash or no effect, but it is plausible that `getchar` makes an assumption about what will point where after an AND.  Unlikely though.

Comment: Aligning the stack and setting up the shadow space made it work.